# How to tackle this $p$-group problem?

Tags: group-theory

**The question is** :

> Let $G$ be a group of order $p^n$ ($n > 0$) where $p$ is a prime.Then for any normal subgroup $H$ of $G$ with $|H| > 1$, show that $|H \cap Z(G)| > 1$.In particular if $|H| = p$ then $H \subseteq Z(G)$.

How can I proceed?Please help me.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider the conjugation action of G on H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints for you to work out:

==  Since $\;H\;$ is normal in $\;G\;$ it is a union of conjugacy classes, each of which has size a power of $\;p\;$

== There is a conjugacy class (in $\;H\;$ and everywhere) with only one element

== Thus there *must be* at least *another* class with only one element.

== Voila!

Comment: I don't understand the fact that for what reason the order of every conjugacy class that partitions $H$ is some power of $p$.Please help me to digest it.

Comment: @Rnbmath Make $\;G\;$ act on $\;H\;$ by conjugation (works because $\;H\lhd G\;$) , then for any $\;h\in H\;$ , we get for its orbit :$$|\mathcal Orb(x)|=[G:G_x]\;,\;\;G_x=\text{ the stabilizer of}\;\;x$$ But the above right side is the index of a $\;p\;$ group and thus **it must** divide the order of $\;G\;$ .

Comment: Yeah.got it.ok.

Comment: I also have confusion in understanding the fact that there should exist at least one conjugacy class other than the conjugacy class containing the identity which contains exactly one element and hence $|H \cap Z(G)| > 1$.

Comment: @R Since the (disjoint!) union of all orbits is $\;H\;$ and **also** this is a $\;p\,-$ group,  and as all the orbits have either size a power of $\;p\;$ or *one* (which is **also** a power of $\;p\;$, certainly: $\;1=p^0\;$) , if there's already one conjugacy class of size one there must be another one (in fact, *at least* $\;p^r-1\;$ for some multiple of $\;p\;$ , other ones) of size one, otherwise we don't get a power of $\;p\;$ for $\;|H|\;$ , which is impossible. Now, check that an element in $\;H\;$ has orbit of size one iff it belongs to $\;Z(G)\;$ .

Comment: Sorry for asking silly question.